# How to redirect to a page after login in Grails using spring security core plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am using Grails 2.1.1 and spring-security-core 1.2.3.7. When I run the app login page is shown because I have shown the login page from url mapping. But when I log in it is not redirecting to home page. It stays on the log-in page.

Here are my url mappings:

```
static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }

    "/"(view:"/login/auth")
    "500"(view:'/error')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the desired `controller` / `action` to your url mapping:

```
static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }

    "/"(controller:"yourcontroller", action: "youraction)
    "500"(view:'/error')
}
```

If `youraction` within `yourcontroller` is secured in any way, spring security will manage the redirecting to the `auth` page and back to `youraction` after a successful authentication.

Comment: no guys, I know what you are saying. But I want to show login page first and after successfull login I want to redirect user to their specific page or dashboard. Thanks for your reply. But can you help in this way ??

Comment: Why not doing this redirect within `yourcontroller`? Here you have access to the user principle. It could be useful to adjust your question. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can make an entry on default success url in `config.groovy` file like this

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = 'controllerName/actionName'
```